# Lookup function combined with multiple criteria and header

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help with this issue:

In tab 1 I have an overview of weeks were someone need to work. There is one row for each week.
But in tab 2 I would like to see which period 1 person is working. When I use a normal VLOOKUP, it only finds the first week and not the rest of the weeks.

I tried index in combination with match formula, but it doesn't work since the "match" is the header of the column in as well tab 1 as tab 2.

=INDEX('Aanvragen DrumDrum'!$A$2:$AA$1000;MATCH(1;('Aanvragen DrumDrum'!$C$2:$C$1000=$C2)*('Aanvragen DrumDrum'!$D$1=$D$1);0);4)

[tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q16Lu.png)
[tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzVZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `query` can be used to get this data.

`=query({A:I},"select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9 where Col2 contains '"&K2&"' ",1)`

[image]

For simplicity, I've shown it in cell `L1` but it would go on your tab2 in cell `B1`.